# Is there a way to get the the cell coordinates as an output

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image: Table]I am currently trying to build a sheet that allows the user to enter a list of stuff they need to do, and what day they need to do it by. Once they enter the day the need to do it by, which is not formatted as a date, but a simple number, it will then appear on the calendar. The issue I am running into is that it seems really hard to get the coordinates of a cell as an output. I am currently trying to use this line
'''=if(MATCH(J4,D5:D29),OFFSET(MATCH(J4,D5:D29),0,-2,1,1), "free")'''
but it keeps saying "the argument must be a range. Please tell me if I am missing something, or there is a way to do this better.

EDIT: The box that has the 2 and #N/A is where the data from the left side is supposed to be going. Since the date is 2, the word "heating" should be showing up in the cell.

Comment: `OFFSET()` function first argument must be a range. Post few sample data and show desired output. Use `INDEX/MATCH` instead.

Comment: In `J5` use `=INDEX($B$5:$B$29,MATCH(J$4,$D$5:$D$29,0))` and in `J6` use `=INDEX($C$5:$C$29,MATCH(J$4,$D$5:$D$29,0))`. Copy to the right. Copy both cells at the same time three rows below and change `J$4` to `J$7` in both cells and repeat...

Comment: Are you on google-sheet? Screenshot shows you are on google sheet. Excel and google-sheet are two different product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use simple `XLOOKUP()` function like-

```
=XLOOKUP(J$4,$D$5:$D$9,$B$5:$B$9)
```

[image]